# Creating a multiplication table with formatting using for loops

Tags: java

I am struggling to create a program that can print a multiplication table using for loops.

My code:

```
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
    System.out.println ("\t\t\tMultiplication Table");
    System.out.println ();

    System.out.println ("\t0\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t");
      for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
      {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("\t" + i * j);
            }
            System.out.println ();
      }
    }
```

I am able to get the top of the table to print as a "header." I am just struggling to print out the left side column from 1-9.

Let me know if there is anything I need to clarify.

Any help would be appreciated. This is for my high school java class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that on the first iteration of either loop, a variable is equal to zero, and when you print their product, it prints zero since any number times zero is zero. A simple fix would be this:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    System.out.println ("\t\t\tMultiplication Table");
    System.out.println ();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
        {
            if(j == 0) System.out.print("\t" + i); 
            else if(i == 0) System.out.print("\t" + j);
            else System.out.print("\t" + i * j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The first `if` statement checks if `j` is zero and prints `i` if it is true. This, in effect, multiplies `i` by one and creates the first column on the left.

The second `if` statement does the same thing, but with `j` and `i` reversed. It creates the first row on the top.

The `else` statement prints the product of `i` and `j` when neither of them equal zero. This creates all of the rows and columns in the middle.

You can get rid of this line:

```
System.out.println("\t0\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t");
```

The role of this line is taken car of by the loops.

The output is:

```
         Multiplication Table

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
2   2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18
3   3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27
4   4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36
5   5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
6   6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54
7   7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63
8   8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72
9   9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` and `j` must start with 1.

```
public static void main (String [] args)
    {
    System.out.println ("\t\t\tMultiplication Table");
    System.out.println ();

    System.out.println ("\t0\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t");
      for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
      {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("\t" + i * j);
            }
            System.out.println ();
      }
    }
```

It will print table from  1 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the i loop but before the j loop try the following:

```
System.out.print(i);
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a tab at the beginning to move your header one tab to the right. Then print the i value before printing the j values in the left column tab.

```
public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println ("\t\t\tMultiplication Table");
        System.out.println ();

        System.out.println ("\t\t0\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("\t" +i);
            for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("\t" + i * j);
            }
            System.out.println ();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, you can start with 1 if you don't want the table from 0

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to add an if statement in the outside loop in order to print the column on the left.

The code:

```
public class MultiplicationTable
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    System.out.println ("\t\t\t\tMultiplication Table");
    System.out.println ();

    System.out.println ("\t0\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t");
      for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
      {
          System.out.print (i);
            for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("\t" + i * j);
            }
            System.out.println ();
      }
      System.out.println ();
}
```

}